# Spark Application - High "Executor Computing Time"

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark application that is now running for 46 hours. While majority of its jobs complete within 25 seconds, specific jobs take hours. Some details are provided below:

```
Task Time   Shuffle Read        Shuffle Write
7.5 h       2.2 MB / 257402     2.9 MB / 128601
```

There are other similar task times off-course having values of 11.3 h, 10.6 h, 9.4 h etc. each of them spending bulk of the activity time on "rdd at DataFrameFunctions.scala:42.". Details for the stage reveals that the time spent by executor on "Executor Computing time". This executor runs at DataNode 1, where the CPU utilization is very normal about 13%. Other boxes (4 more worker nodes) have very nominal CPU utilization.

When the Shuffle Read is within 5000 records, this is extremely fast and completes with 25 seconds, as stated previously. Nothing is appended to the logs (spark/hadoop/hbase), neither anything is noticed at `/tmp` or `/var/tmp` location which will indicate some disk related activity is in progress.

I am clueless about what is going wrong. Have been struggling with this for quite some time now. The versions of software used are as follows:

```
Hadoop    : 2.7.2
Zookeeper : 3.4.9
Kafka     : 2.11-0.10.1.1
Spark     : 2.1.0
HBase     : 1.2.6
Phoenix   : 4.10.0
```

Some configurations on the spark default file.

```
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
spark.eventLog.dir               hdfs://SDCHDPMAST1:8111/data1/spark-event
spark.history.fs.logDirectory    hdfs://SDCHDPMAST1:8111/data1/spark-event
spark.yarn.jars                  hdfs://SDCHDPMAST1:8111/user/appuser/spark/share/lib/*.jar
spark.driver.maxResultSize       5G
spark.deploy.zookeeper.url       SDCZKPSRV01

spark.executor.memory                   12G
spark.driver.memory                     10G
spark.executor.heartbeatInterval        60s
spark.network.timeout                   300s
```

Is there any way I can reduce the time spent on "Executor Computing time"?

Comment: I'm facing the same behavior on one of the cluster, did you found any idea to reduce the executor computing time ? Your jobs are batched or streamed?

Answer (score 0):

The job performing on the specific dataset is skewed. Because of the skewness, jobs are taking more than expected.